# Retrieving data from MySQL using Nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm new to javascript and nodeJS.

I'm having some trouble trying to run a SQL query to retrieve data using Nodejs.

I created a connection module (db.js) but unable to get the results from executing controller.js.

I know for sure that the connection module is working well as I manage to retrieve data from DB if I were to swap the resolve(connection) to queries.

Please help me take a look where did I go wrong.

Here is the db.js

```
var mysql = require('mysql2');
var Client = require('ssh2').Client;
var ssh = new Client();

var db = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    ssh.on('ready', function () {
        ssh.forwardOut(
            '127.0.0.1',
            12345,
            '127.0.0.1',
            3306,
            function (err, stream) {
                if (err) throw err;
                let connection = mysql.createConnection({
                    host: '127.0.0.1',
                    user: 'username',
                    password: 'password',
                    database: 'test',
                    stream: stream
                });

                connection.connect(function (err) {
                    if (!err) {
                        resolve(connection)
                    } else {
                        reject(err);
                    }
                });
            });
    }).connect({
        host: 'hostname',
        port: 22,
        username: 'username',
        password: 'password'
    });
});

module.exports = db;
```

Here is the controller.js

```
var database = require('./db');

module.exports.getcats = (function(req, res) {
    database().then(function (connection) {
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM listUnit", function (error, results, fields) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
                return;
            }
            res.write(results);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: What are the logs tellin? What is the log output for results?

Comment: Hi Simon. Nothing came up after I ran the command (node controller.js). However, if I were to put the query into db.js and run it, the result of the query will appear on the console.

Answer (score 1):

If your code is as you describe it above, nothing visible will happen when you run

```
node controller.js
```

This is because your controller module *defines* an exported function that opens a database connection and makes a query, but it never *invokes* that function.

Probably in a real application you would use the exported `getcats()` function in some other module, like you've used the `db()` function.  But, if you wanted to, you could modify your controller so that the code *defines*, *exports*, and *invokes* the function, giving you the result of your query when you run it from the command line:

```
var database = require('./db');

// define the function
function getcats(req, res) {
    database().then(function (connection) {
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM listUnit", function (error, results, fields) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
                return;
            }
            res.write(results);
        });
    });
}

// export the function for use in other places
module.exports = getcats;

// invoke so it runs the query when you call "node controller.js"
getcats();
```